# Crear clases Java de un WSDL y XSD con el Pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven, wsdl, xsd

Tengo un wsdl y xsd con las siguientes cabeceras

wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://wsPersonas.soap.servicios.primma.com" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="wsPersonasService" targetNamespace="http://wsPersonas.soap.servicios.primma.com">
  <types>
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://wsPersonas.soap.servicios.primma.com" schemaLocation="WsPersonasService_schema1.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://wsPersonas.soap.servicios.primma.com" targetNamespace="http://wsPersonas.soap.servicios.primma.com" version="1.0">
```

No son míos y no puedo modificarlos.

Estoy intentando generar las clases Java en mi proyecto Maven (con Maven clean and Install) pero no se me generan. Este es mi pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>es.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>cesskafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>es.xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>WsPersonasService-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>WsPersonasService-client</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
        <axis2.version>1.7.9</axis2.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    </properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>create-client</id>
        
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Generates JAVA source files from the WSDL -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${axis2.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <packageName>es.xxx.wspersonasserviceclient</packageName>
                            <wsdlFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/WsPersonasService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            <schema>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/WsPersonasService_schema1.xsd</schema>  
                            <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>openejb-javaagent</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/es</directory>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/es</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/src/es</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/xmlbeans/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    </profile>
</profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
           <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

¿Qué le faltaría al pom.xml para que se me generen las clases? Sobretodo para el XSD ya que en otro proyecto hemos utilizado wsdl sin XSD y ha funcionado correctamente, he mirado en foros pero no he conseguido nada

si necesitáis más información no dudéis en decidmelo.

Muchas gracias

Un saludo.

Comment: No parece que tus ficheros estén definiendo ningún mensaje SOAP. ¿Estás seguro de qué son los que tocan?

Comment: Sí, sólo puse las cabeceras del WSDL y XSD, el Pom.xml lo puse entero.